# Is it possible to Mysql event over a range of hours every day?

Tags: mysql

I have a Mysql event created on my data base it works fine but I would like to run just in a specific time interval.

This is my actual event:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`admin`@`%` 
EVENT `respaldoRegPosition` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 15 MINUTE STARTS '2017-08-11 14:59:30' ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE DO BEGIN
    -- INSERT INTO BACKUP TABLE

INSERT INTO regPositionBACKUP (idPosition, deviceId, lastPositionTime, divisionew, longitude, divisionns, latitude, direction, gradeLon, gradeLat, speed) 
-- GET DATA
    SELECT idPosition, deviceId, lastPositionTime, divisionew, longitude, divisionns, latitude, direction, gradeLon, gradeLat, speed 
    FROM regPosition 
    WHERE regPosition.lastPositionTime < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH) 
    ORDER BY regPosition.lastPositionTime LIMIT 3000;

-- DELETE DATA FROM ORIGINAL TABLE
    DELETE FROM regPosition WHERE regPosition.lastPositionTime < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH) ORDER BY regPosition.lastPositionTime LIMIT 3000;

END
```

Is it possible to do this?

I would like it to run every day between 00:00:00 and 06:00:00 at intervals of 10 minutes.

I can create an event with 10 minutes intervals of excecution without problem (ON SCHEDULE EVERY 10 MINUTE) but how can I run this to work every day (ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY) and be excecuted by each 10 minutes in a time interval.

Thank you

Comment: It is possible to do that. Now.. what's your actual question? You want someone to write code for you? You want this executed by "night".. how is someone supposed to know what night means for you? You can see that event accepts the INTERVAL (15 minutes) and WHEN to start. So, make it run every 24 hours starting at the date you believe night is.

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to make the question. I'm going to edit the thread.

Comment: I have already edited the post I hope the information I added be of some help

Answer (score 1):

Looking for information I found this thread with a solution to my problem.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/80050

Thank you all.

[EDIT]

This was the solution I have implemented:

```
BEGIN

DECLARE rightnow DATETIME;
DECLARE hh,mm TINYINT;

    SET rightnow = NOW();   
    SET hh = HOUR(rightnow);
    SET mm = MINUTE(rightnow);

    IF hh >= 02 AND hh <= 06 THEN

        -- INSERT INTO BACKUP TABLE
        INSERT INTO regPositionBACKUP (idPosition, deviceId, lastPositionTime, divisionew, longitude, divisionns, latitude, direction, gradeLon, gradeLat, speed) 

        -- GET DATA
        SELECT idPosition, deviceId, lastPositionTime, divisionew, longitude, divisionns, latitude, direction, gradeLon, gradeLat, speed 
                FROM regPosition 
                WHERE regPosition.lastPositionTime < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH) 
                ORDER BY regPosition.lastPositionTime LIMIT 3000;

        -- DELETE DATA FROM ORIGINAL TABLE
        DELETE FROM regPosition WHERE regPosition.lastPositionTime < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH) ORDER BY regPosition.lastPositionTime LIMIT 3000;

    END IF;

END
```

So adding this condition to the code of the event I could run the event every 10 minutes always but It will be executed only in the time interval that I set (02:00-06:00)